# Need to apostille my background check via US Department of State; what are the steps after digital fingerprinting at USPS?

Tags: visas, usa

For a visa, I am required to have an FBI background check, and to additionally [apostille](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/records-and-authentications/authenticate-your-document/apostille-requirements.html) it. I have to do it through the US Department of State according to the [visa instructions](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/us-sanfrancisco-en/wpge/m_20623/contents.do).

> FBI criminal background check apostilled by U.S. Department of State, Office of Authentications

> Fill out the application form electronically at https://www.edo.cjis.gov/#/  and get finger print at USPS (Appointment only)

> Federal documents such as FBI clearances are authenticated by U.S. Department of State, Office of Authentications https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/records-and-authentications/authenticate-your-document/office-of-authentications.html

But two things: I still haven't gotten my email results back from the USPS / FBI and it's been 2 weeks, and second, am I supposed to print it out and send it or do I need to have it officially be printed as an official document?

Comment: FBI background checks can take up to _several months_ (and some never come back). Although I doubt the respective departments are so busy right now.

Comment: Oh what the. The USPS said that it would take about 2-3 days which is why i was concerned.